# Update User Meta after Registration

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In wordpress, after a user registers, I am using the function below to create two pages of two different custom post types, and I then need to store a custom meta value in their user data to assist with redirects later. I've found that if I specify custom meta values during registration (on registration form), I can retrieve these values later with :

```
global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $theirRedirectKey = $current_user->rpr_redirect_key;
```

However, in the following functions.php snippet, I can't the meta value to save for retrieval later.

```
function after_registration($user_id){
    // Get the Newly Created User ID
    $the_user = get_userdata($user_id);

    // Get the Newly Created User Name
    $new_user_name = $the_user->user_login;

    // Create a unique Tour Code Prefix from User ID
    $tourPrefix = $the_user->ID;

    // Check for Tour Code Key if entered into registration form
    $enteredKey = $the_user->rpr_redirect_key;

    if($enteredKey == ''){
        //Create the first Tour Builder Page
        $tourBuilder = array();
        $tourBuilder['post_title'] = $new_user_name . '| Custom Educational Tour';
        // Next line may not be important after hubpages are set up.
        $tourBuilder['post_name'] = 'builder-' . $tourPrefix;
        $tourBuilder['post_type'] = 'builder';
        $tourBuilder['post_content'] = 'This is the content!';
        $tourBuilder['post_author'] = $user_id;
        $tourBuilder['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $tour_id = wp_insert_post( $tourBuilder );

        // Build hubpage
        $hubpage = array();
        $hubpage['post_title'] = $new_user_name . '\'s Hubpage';
        // URL must be unique
        $hubpage['post_name'] = $new_user_name;
        $hubpage['post_type'] = 'hubpages';
        $hubpage['post_author'] = $user_id;
        $hubpage['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $hub_id = wp_insert_post( $hubpage );

        //Update User with proper redirect keys for some reason this line doesn't work.
        add_user_meta($the_user, 'rpr_redirect_key', '/hubpage/' . $new_user_name, true);
    }

}
add_action('user_register', 'after_registration');
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
add_user_meta( $the_user, 'rpr_redirect_key', '/hubpage/' . $new_user_name, true);
```

`$the_user` isn't the ID. Try `$the_user->ID` or `$user_id` instead